# Add another object into existing JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm not sure I'm asking this exactly right, but here's the situation.

I have an existing JSON object like this and I need to "inject" a new object into this where indicated:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "stat_tag": "API",
    "layers": [{
            "type": "cartodb",
            "options": {
                "sql": "SELECT * FROM mytable)",
                "cartocss": "mytable{marker-width: 10;}",
                "cartocss_version": "2.1.0"
            }
        }
        //INSERT NEW OBJECT HERE
    ]
}
```

The object I need to inject is stored as a variable, I just don't know how to push it into the existing object in the right place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Push it into `layers`:

```
myObj.layers.push(newEl);
```

As the `layers` is an array `push` will add the `newEl` at the end of it.

```
var myObj = {
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "stat_tag": "API",
    "layers": [{
            "type": "cartodb",
            "options": {
                "sql": "SELECT * FROM mytable)",
                "cartocss": "mytable{marker-width: 10;}",
                "cartocss_version": "2.1.0"
            }
        }
        //INSERT NEW OBJECT HERE
    ]
};


var newEl = {
    "name": "Tushar"
}; // Object to add


myObj.layers.push(newEl);

console.log(myObj);
```

Comment: Okay, so in this script, what is `myObj` and what is `newEl`?

Comment: @jonmrich When there is no key `layers` on which you are pushing `newEl`

Comment: I think I see the problem. I over-simplified my example a bit, so your solution is right for the example, but not what I actually have. I really need to push the new object into something like this: `layers: Array[1]0: Objectoptions: Objectsub: SubLayertype: "cartodb"__proto__: Objectlength: 1__proto__: Array[0]` So, basically, I need to push object 1 into this layers object. How do I do that?

Comment: I keep trying to push in the new data and `console.log` the entire object, but my console just returns "2"